# Can you view existing JavaFX bindings?

Tags: javafx, properties, binding

I'm trying to debug an issue where a DoubleProperty is apparently bound to something and I haven't been able to figure out what.

I'm wondering if there's a way to ease that with something like:

```
for (Binding binding : myProperty().getBindings()) {
System.out.println("Binding: " + binding);
}
```

But I can't find a way to inspect a property's current bindings.  Does one exist?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do this in code.

Comment: The core implementations store the target `ObservableValue` in the `XXXPropertyBase` abstract class. You can attach a debugger and inspect the field or attempt to get the value of the field via reflection (may require an `--add-opens` option). But neither the API of `Property` nor its standard implementations provide a direct way.